125034 v2.8 / 2024-12-25 WR
I would like to post a question here. It might be long and experimental. I hope I write the things down accurately.
I am developing a game that generates puzzles every day (https://125034.pages.dev/). It's my opinion that these puzzles are like Einstein's Riddle in 1D.
A few days later, it will generate the following puzzle:

2024-12-25 WR
Rearrange the digits in ⟨125034⟩ to meet the rules below.
⟨5th 4th 3rd 2nd 1st 0th⟩
✅Match
⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)
⟨⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩
Sim⟨ ⁵ᵗʰ4 ⁴ᵗʰ2 ³ʳᵈ1 ²ⁿᵈ0 ¹ˢᵗ5 ⁰ᵗʰ3 ⟩ ≥ 1
⛔Avoid
⟦0,2⟧ ∋ 1,4,5
4th → a, 0th → b, ab=0+5n
Jump(0,4) ≤ 1
#125034_v2.8

A road-bot in the game will suggest that there are 8 ways to deduce the answer. Can you reveal them by completing the following graph?

I will select an answer about a week later. Hopefully it will be a correct one with the most number of upvotes.

Example and formal description
Example riddle:

Answer:


Each vertex is a partial answer. A partial answer consists of digits submitted in correct positions. Given two partial answers $s$ and $t$, we write

(a) $\boldsymbol{s\leq t}$ if every digit in $s$ is a digit in $t$;

(b) $\boldsymbol{s < t}$ if $s\leq t$ and $s \neq t$.



Each edge is labeled by a set of patterns. We write $\boldsymbol{s\overset{E}{\longrightarrow}t}$ if there is an edge from vertex $s$ to $t$ labeled by $E$.

If $s_0\overset{E_0}{\longrightarrow}t_0$, then the following hold:

(a) We have $s_0 < t_0$ and we can deduce the partial answer $t_0$ from $s_0$ using the patterns in $E_0$.

(b) If $E$ is a set of patterns and a proper subset of $E_0$ ($E\subsetneq E_0$), then for any partial answer $t$ such that $s_0 < t$, we are unable to deduce $t$ from $s_0$ using $E$.

(c) If $t$ is a partial answer such that we can deduce $t$ from $s_0$ using $E_0$, then $t\leq t_0$.


In other words, the edge indicates that there is a reasoning from $s_0$ to $t_0$ using $E_0$, where $E_0$ is minimal and $t_0$ is maximal in a certain sense.

Given a vertex $s_0$, if $s_0\overset{E_1}{\longrightarrow}t_1$ and $s_0\overset{E_2}{\longrightarrow}t_2$, then one of the following holds:

(a) they represent the same edge; or

(b) $(E_1 \setminus E_2) \neq \emptyset$ and $(E_2 \setminus E_1) \neq \emptyset$. That is, $E_1$ contains a pattern that $E_2$ does not, and vice versa.


Therefore, different edges from $s_0$ represent different reasoning.

Each path from the root vertex to the final vertex represents a way to solve the riddle.
It is my current view that in many cases these paths resemble or transcend human reasoning.



Statistics and hints

 Based on the graph, we can do some statistics. Firstly, we consider how often a pattern is used per path. Given a pattern $\pi_0$, we consider the quantity $$\dfrac{\sum_{P} \sum_{E\in P} 1_{E}(\pi_0)}{\sum_{P} 1},$$ where $\sum_{P}$ is the sum over all paths $P$, $\sum_{E\in P}$ is the sum over all edge labels $E$ of a path $P$, and $1_{E}$ is an indicator function: $$ 1_{E}(\pi) = \left\{\begin{array}{lc}{1\,\,\mbox{if $\pi$ is in $E$}}\\{0\,\,\mbox{otherwise.}}\end{array}\right.$$ The larger the value of this quantity, the more often $\pi_0$ is used.


 We have the following data for our example riddle:



 It suggests that when one is trying to solve the riddle, (r1) will be the most used, being involved an average of 2.67 times.


 Next, we consider how the patterns are related to each other. In view of $$  \begin{align*}\sum_{P} \sum_{E\in P} 1_{E}(\pi) &= \sum_{E} \sum_{P\,: \,E\in P} 1_{E}(\pi) \\&= \sum_{E} 1_{E}(\pi) \sum_{P\,: \,E\in P} 1 \\&:= \sum_{E} 1_{E}(\pi) N_E,\end{align*}$$ where $N_E := \sum_{P\,: \,E\in P} 1$ is the number of paths including $E$, we consider the quantity $$\dfrac{\sum_{E} 1_{E}(\pi_i) 1_{E}(\pi_j) N_E}{\sqrt{\sum_{E} 1_{E}(\pi_i) N_E}\sqrt{\sum_{E} 1_{E}(\pi_j) N_E}}$$ for any two patterns $\pi_i$, $\pi_j$. It is between $0$ and $1$ by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. The closer the value is to $1$, the more likely $\pi_i$ and $\pi_j$ are used together.


 We have the following data for our example riddle:



 It suggests that (r1) and (f1) are most related to each other (0.62).


 We end by presenting the data for the game riddle:





If I understood the rules right and did not a mistake then the answer is rot13(svirsbhegjbbarmrebguerr). But I found it following the way different from suggested by the graph. Anyway, the graph form is not convenient to fill.

On the other hand, I like your thorough approach, +1.

@AlexRavsky Thanks for playing my game! You are correct and I hope it brought you some good times. Your comments are helpful to me.

I am the OP. Since the game period is over but there are no answers, I would like to write one. You are welcome to comment on my answer or the game.
As it seems like the leftmost path is simpler than the paths at the right, my approach is like a U sharp: First, I follow the leftmost path to find the answer. Then, I fill in the vertices. Finally I fill in the edge labels.
Notation: if nth -> a, then I write [nth] = a.

Step 1

Reasoning:
We consider where to place 0. By ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」, it is not in the left corner (5th), and by ⛔「4th → a, 0th → b, ab=0+5n」, it is not at 4th or 0th.
Therefore, 0 = [3rd] | [2nd] | [1st]:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
(1) |   |   | 0 |   |   |   |
    |-----------------------|
(2) |   |   |   | 0 |   |   |
    |-----------------------|
(3) |   |   |   |   | 0 |   |
    -------------------------

If (1) or (2) holds, then ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」 implies:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
(4) |   |   | 0 |   |   | 4 |
    |-----------------------|
(5) | 4 |   |   | 0 |   |   |
    -------------------------

Both (4) and (5) are contradictions, because ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」 requires that 4 is not in corners.
Therefore, (1) and (2) do not hold, and (3) holds instead. We get our first partial answer:

     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Ans1 |   |   |   |   | 0 |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 5 |   | 3 | 4 |
-------------------------

Then, in view of ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」, we have 4 = [5th] | [4th]. As ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」 implies that 4 is not in the left corner, we get 4 = [4th]:

     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev |   |   |   |   | 0 |   |▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Ans2 |   | 4 |   |   | 0 |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 5 |   | 3 |   |
-------------------------

■


     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev |   | 4 |   |   | 0 |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 5 |   | 3 |   |
-------------------------

Reasoning:
To match ✅「Sim⟨ ⁵ᵗʰ4 ⁴ᵗʰ2 ³ʳᵈ1 ²ⁿᵈ0 ¹ˢᵗ5 ⁰ᵗʰ3 ⟩ ≥ 1」, we need at least one positional digit agreed with ⟨421053⟩. Since 0 and 1 are adjacent by ✅「⟨⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩」, all of the 5th, 4th, 3rd, 2nd, and 1st positions cannot be an agreed position.
Consequently, 0th is an agreed position. We get

     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev |   | 4 |   |   | 0 |   |▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Ans3 |   | 4 |   |   | 0 | 3 |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 5 |   |   |   |
-------------------------

Then, it follows from ✅「⟨⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩」 that 1 = [2nd]:

     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev |   | 4 |   |   | 0 | 3 |▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Ans4 |   | 4 |   | 1 | 0 | 3 |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   | 2 | 5 |   |   |   |
-------------------------

■
End result of step 1:


Step 2
After finishing step 1, we get the answer, so we are able to fill in all of the vertices.
End result of step 2:


Step 3
We start filling in the remaining edge labels. We first deal with edges that only include 1 pattern.
Let us just explain one edge:


     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev | 5 |   |   | 1 |   | 3 |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   | 2 |   | 0 |   | 4 |
-------------------------

Reasoning:
We consider what [3rd] is. If it is 0 or 4, then we cannot avoid ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」. Therefore, it has to be 2:

     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev | 5 |   |   | 1 |   | 3 |▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Next | 5 |   | 2 | 1 |   | 3 |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   |   |   | 0 |   | 4 |
-------------------------

■
End result of step 3:


Step 4
We can use the same reasoning as in step 1 to fill in the leftmost remaining path.
End result of step 4:


Step 5
Next, we have


     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev | 5 |   |   |   |   |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 |   | 0 | 3 | 4 |
-------------------------

Reasoning:
We consider what [2nd] is. If it is 0 or 4, then we cannot avoid ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」. Therefore, we have
(1) [2nd] = 1|2|3.
(2) We show that [2nd] = 1 actually.

Suppose on the contrary [2nd] = 2|3:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | 5 |   |   | * |   |   |
    -------------------------

Then, by ✅「⟨⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩」 and ⛔「4th → a, 0th → b, ab=0+5n」, there are two possibilities:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
(3) | 5 | 1 | 0 | * |   |   |
    |-----------------------|
(4) | 5 |   |   | * | 0 | 1 |
    -------------------------

To avoid ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」, we have

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
(5) | 5 | 1 | 0 | * |   | 4 |
    |-----------------------|
(6) | 5 | 4 |   | * | 0 | 1 |
    -------------------------

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   | 2 |   |   | 3 |   |
-------------------------

Both (5) and (6) are contradictions because we cannot match ✅「Sim⟨ ⁵ᵗʰ4 ⁴ᵗʰ2 ³ʳᵈ1 ²ⁿᵈ0 ¹ˢᵗ5 ⁰ᵗʰ3 ⟩ ≥ 1」.

We have verified (2). Therefore, we get

     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev | 5 |   |   |   |   |   |▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Next | 5 |   |   | 1 |   |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   | 2 |   | 0 | 3 | 4 |
-------------------------

■
End result of step 5:


Step 6
We consider the edges of the vertex <5**1**>. Our previous step shows that the reasoning of <5*****> => <5**1**> includes four patterns. Since <5**1**> is "maximal" in the deduction, we see that the outing edges of <5**1**> should use a pattern other than that four patterns. Given that 5 is in the left corner (5th), the pattern ⛔「⟦0,2⟧ ∋ 1,4,5」 has no use. Therefore, all of the outing edges of <5**1**> should use ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」.
End result of step 6:


Step 7
We consider the two edges for <5**1**> => <5**1*3>. They correspond to two types of reasoning: (i) Fix a digit and consider where it is placed; (ii) Fix a position and consider which digit is placed there.


     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev | 5 |   |   | 1 |   |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   | 2 |   | 0 | 3 | 4 |
-------------------------

Reasoning:
Observe that to match ✅「Sim⟨ ⁵ᵗʰ4 ⁴ᵗʰ2 ³ʳᵈ1 ²ⁿᵈ0 ¹ˢᵗ5 ⁰ᵗʰ3 ⟩ ≥ 1」, we need at least one of the following holds:
(1) 2 = [4th] or 3 = [0th].

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | 5 | * |   | 1 |   | * |
    -------------------------

Let us consider where to place 3. By ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」, 4 is to the left of 3. So there are four possibilities:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
(2) | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 |   |   |
    |-----------------------|
(3) | 5 | 4 |   | 1 | 3 |   |
    |-----------------------|
(4) | 5 |   | 4 | 1 | 3 |   |
    |-----------------------|
(5) | 5 |   |   | 1 |   | 3 |
    -------------------------

Note that if (2) or (3) holds, then we cannot match (1), and if (4) holds, then we cannot match ✅「⟨⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩」. Therefore, case (5) holds.
■


     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev | 5 |   |   | 1 |   |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   | 2 |   | 0 | 3 | 4 |
-------------------------

Reasoning:
Same as before, to match ✅「Sim⟨ ⁵ᵗʰ4 ⁴ᵗʰ2 ³ʳᵈ1 ²ⁿᵈ0 ¹ˢᵗ5 ⁰ᵗʰ3 ⟩ ≥ 1」, we need at least one of the following holds:
(1) 2 = [4th] or 3 = [0th].

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | 5 | * |   | 1 |   | * |
    -------------------------

Let us consider what [0th] is. By ⛔「4th → a, 0th → b, ab=0+5n」, it is not 0. By (1), it is not 2. By ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」, it is not 4. Therefore, it is 3:

     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev | 5 |   |   | 1 |   |   |▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Next | 5 |   |   | 1 |   | 3 |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   | 2 |   | 0 |   | 4 |
-------------------------

■
End result of step 7:


Step 8
Next, we consider the two edges for <5**1**> => <54*10*>. One of them corresponds to the same reasoning as step 1. We focus on the other:


     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Prev | 5 |   |   | 1 |   |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
|   | 2 |   | 0 | 3 | 4 |
-------------------------

Reasoning:
To match ✅「⟨⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩」 and avoid ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」 at the same time, there are only two possibilities:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
(1) | 5 |   | 0 | 1 |   | 4 |
    |-----------------------|
(2) | 5 | 4 |   | 1 | 0 |   |
    -------------------------

Since 4 is not in the right corner by ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」, case (2) holds actually.
■
End result of step 8:


Step 9
Only one unfilled edge label remains. Note that in step 1, after reaching <*4*103>, if we do not have ⛔「⟦0,2⟧ ∋ 1,4,5」, then both <245103> and <542103> pass all of the other patterns.
Therefore, we have to include ⛔「⟦0,2⟧ ∋ 1,4,5」 if we want to get [5th] = 5.
On the other hand, we have to exclude one of the patterns used in the other outing edge of <******> (the root vertex), because different edges represent different reasoning.
Among the patterns ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」, ⛔「4th → a, 0th → b, ab=0+5n」, and ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」, it seems that the first one should be kept. It turns out that we can exclude ⛔「4th → a, 0th → b, ab=0+5n」 here.

Reasoning:
We consider what [5th] is. Let X := [5th]. By ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」, we have
(1) X = 2|3|5.
(2) We show that it is a contradiction if X = 2 or 3.

Suppose X = 2|3. Then, regardless of the value of X, by ✅「⟨? ⋯ 4 ⋯ (?−2) ⋯⟩ (?≠4)」 and ✅「⟨⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩」, we have
(3) ⟨X ⋯ 4 ⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩ (X=2|3).
By considering the possible positions of 0, we see that there are four possibilities:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
(4) | X | 4 | 0 | 1 |   |   |
    |-----------------------|
(5) | X |   |   | 0 |   |   |
    |-----------------------|
(6) | X |   |   |   | 0 |   |
    |-----------------------|
(7) | X |   |   |   | 1 | 0 |
    -------------------------

Cases (4) and (5) cannot hold if we want to avoid ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」. Therefore, it remains to show that cases (6) and (7) are impossible too.
(8.1) Suppose case (6) holds. By (3) and ⛔「Jump(0,4) ≤ 1」, we have

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | X | 4 |   |   | 0 |   |
    -------------------------

Then, to match ✅「Sim⟨ ⁵ᵗʰ4 ⁴ᵗʰ2 ³ʳᵈ1 ²ⁿᵈ0 ¹ˢᵗ5 ⁰ᵗʰ3 ⟩ ≥ 1」 and ✅「⟨⋯ Perm(0,1) ⋯⟩」 at the same time, we need 3 = [0th]:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | X | 4 |   |   | 0 | 3 |
    -------------------------

As X = 2|3, it follows that X = 2:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | 2 | 4 |   |   | 0 | 3 |
    -------------------------

It is a contradiction, however, as we would match ⛔「⟦0,2⟧ ∋ 1,4,5」.
(8.2) Finally, suppose case (7) holds:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | X |   |   |   | 1 | 0 |
    -------------------------

To avoid ⛔「⟦0,2⟧ ∋ 1,4,5」, we cannot have X = 2. Therefore, X = 3:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | 3 |   |   |   | 1 | 0 |
    -------------------------

Then, to match ✅「Sim⟨ ⁵ᵗʰ4 ⁴ᵗʰ2 ³ʳᵈ1 ²ⁿᵈ0 ¹ˢᵗ5 ⁰ᵗʰ3 ⟩ ≥ 1」, we need [4th] = 2:

    -------------------------
    |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|
    |-----------------------|
    | 3 | 2 |   |   | 1 | 0 |
    -------------------------

We would still match ⛔「⟦0,2⟧ ∋ 1,4,5」, which is a contradiction.

We have verified (2). Accordingly, we get

     -------------------------
     |5th|4th|3rd|2nd|1st|0th|▒
     |-----------------------|▒
Ans1 | 5 |   |   |   |   |   |▒
     -------------------------▒
      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

--- Idle ---
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 |   | 0 | 3 | 4 |
-------------------------

■
End result of step 9:

Done!

Remarks:

✅「Sim⟨ ⁵ᵗʰ4 ⁴ᵗʰ2 ³ʳᵈ1 ²ⁿᵈ0 ¹ˢᵗ5 ⁰ᵗʰ3 ⟩ ≥ 1」 is related to derangement.
Step 9 can also be done by using the hints. We just need to check which patterns have nonzero correlation with ⛔「⟦0,2⟧ ∋ 1,4,5」.

